# What is the minimum temperature required to create a cloud chamber with isopropyl alcohol?

Tags: thermodynamics, particle-physics, radiation, home-experiment, radioactivity

Just as a preface, I am a rookie. As the title says, I am wondering what is the minimum temperature required to successfully create a cloud chamber and visualise the passage of ionizing radiation?

I have a 4x4cm Peltier (TEC1-12710) element, which I was able to push down to **-30 °c**. I can not get it to go lower. **Is that temperature low enough (I plan on using it with 98% isopropyl alcohol)?**

I plan on building a 4.2x4.2x4.2cm sealed enclosure block around the peltier as the chamber, and put a magnifying glass on top to see whats going on inside.

Comment: see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pewTySxfTQk  Dry ice  has   block of dry ice has a surface temperature of -109.3 degrees Fahrenheit (-78.5 degrees C).  so it does not seem enough

Comment: read this using a peltier  http://digitalcommons.calpoly.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1014&context=physsp

Comment: Hi Anna, dry ice is really hard to get in my country, and thus is not really an option. I really would like to attempt this using Peltier module(s). Ive read the paper (thank you),  they used a stacked Peltier unit reaching down to -65 which I know is enough. The question is however, could -30°c  be possibly enough in order to the cloud to form? Since thats as low as my Peltier module can get to.  I know it can not go lower. Unfortunately, none of the above links gave a definitive answer about the required temperatures in a cloud chamber.  Thank you anyway, nice paper, might be useful.

Comment: have a look at this  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/168873/cloud-chamber-with-normal-ice  you could use the trick the link used to have tracks with water ice

Comment: @DominikAntal Its long time since this question was asked but, did you get answer to this? I am also interested to know if -30c is enough.

Comment: @mj6174 No, but eventually I managed to go as low as -50 (which was enough) using copper water cooler block with good thermal paste, circulating icy water to cool the hot side of the TEC.